# AIRFLOW-DOCKER connect to SQL Server: Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have 2 tasks in my dags. First, is for the API requests and storing response into json file. 2nd, is to read the json file and insert it into SQL SERVER EXPRESS in my windows system.

I am using airflow with docker. But, now, I am receiving an error `Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)`. Need your help (New to airflow and docker)

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=spotify_dag/run_id=scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00/task_id=save_to_db/attempt=22.log
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1160} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.save_to_db scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1160} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.save_to_db scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1357} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1358} INFO - Starting attempt 22 of 22
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1359} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1378} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): save_to_db> on 2022-06-05 00:00:00+00:00
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 3490 to run task
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'spotify_dag', 'save_to_db', 'scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '158', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/spotify_dags.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpvy218ngm', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpd9eu2rfd']
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 158: Subtask save_to_db
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {task_command.py:370} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.save_to_db scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host 93b139943859
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1572} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=***@example.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=spotify_dag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=save_to_db
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=22
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-06-05T00:00:00+00:00
[2022-06-06, 12:07:41 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server
[2022-06-06, 12:08:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1890} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 171, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 189, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/save_to_db.py", line 87, in call_save_to_db
    a.save_to_db()
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/save_to_db.py", line 32, in save_to_db
    Trusted_Connection="yes")
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
[2022-06-06, 12:08:11 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=spotify_dag, task_id=save_to_db, execution_date=20220605T000000, start_date=20220606T120741, end_date=20220606T120811
[2022-06-06, 12:08:11 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:97} ERROR - Failed to execute job 158 for task save_to_db (('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'); 3490)
[2022-06-06, 12:08:11 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-06-06, 12:08:11 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: `Trusted_Connection="yes"`? Have you managed to get Windows Authentication working inside a Docker container? Perhaps you meant to use SQL Login authentication instead and specify a username and password in your connection string?

Comment: In my experience, "Login timeout expired" typically means that you can't reach the database server at a network level. That could be for myriad reasons (e.g. you have the server name incorrect, there's a firewall somewhere between the client and server, etc). Try the most simple thing - can you establish a connection from your docker instance to the database server on its port (typically 1433 - check with your administrator)?